# Is it possible to have an Eclipse project w/ one package that executes as a Android app, and a second package that executes as a Java SE app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, netbeans

I know that must sound crazy... Here's the situation. I am developing an Android application in Eclipse. The Java Swing-based level designer for the Android app is in Java SE and currently runs in NetBeans. This editor program creates and serializes levels which are then deserialized by the android app. The serialized levels consist of about 12 classes and run in both Java SE and Android. These classes are the glue holding the two programs together. I'd like a setup like so:

com.androidSpecific
com.sharedData
com.JavaSESpecific.

Where I can click on some stuff and run the level editor, and then click on some other stuff and load up the Android app. Is there a way to make dream come true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up two different projects in Eclipse. You can tell Eclipse that one Project depends on the other to resolve shared code. Or, you can extract the common-code to a third project, and have the Android and JSE projects contain the -specific code for those environments.

Comment: Is that a copy on write situation?

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to, sorry. To be more clear, what I mean is to put the Android code in one project, and the JSE code in a second, and set one project to depend on the other so that you can re-use code from the first in the second (or put the common code in a third project). Eclipse builds things at the "project" level, so you can organize each "project" as a single module of a larger system.

Comment: when I create a separate project and link the code from one to the other, it places it in a separate folder outside the src directory. How do I access that data, as in how to import the classes?

Comment: How are you linking the code? In the properties for Project B, under Java Build Path add Project A to the "Projects" tab. No source code should be copied when doing this; Eclipse merely includes Project A's output on the classpath when compiling/running Project B. You would then just import classes/packages as you would any other dependency. Are you linking the files some other way?